# Edit user profile template with module

Tags: 7, theming, users

How can I edit the user profile template in Drupal 7?

I've created a module called sporthron in my project.

sporthron.module contains :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function sporthron_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $theme = array();
  $theme['user_profile'] = array(
    'template' => 'user-profile',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'sporthron') . '/templates',
   );
  return $theme;
}
```

And here is the path to the template :
/sites/all/modules/sporthron/templates/user-profile.tpl.php which contains :

```
<div class="profile"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php print render($user_profile); ?>
</div>

TEST
```

But this template is never used. Whatever edit I made is not applied.

And yes my module is enabled. Do you know how can I apply this template

Comment: change the location of your template sites/all/themes/your_theme/templates/user-profile.tpl.php

Comment: @Vicky8888 Why should I move to this directory if I'm using a module and not a theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to implement the hook_theme_registry_alter()

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_registry_alter().
 */
function sporthron_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {

  $module_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'sporthron');

  // Find all .tpl.php files in this module's folder recursively.
  $template_file_objects = drupal_find_theme_templates($theme_registry, '.tpl.php', $module_path);
  // Iterate through all found template file objects.
  foreach ($template_file_objects as $key => $template_file_object) {
    // If the template has not already been overridden by a theme.
    if (!isset($theme_registry[$key]['theme path']) || !preg_match('#/themes/#', $theme_registry[$key]['theme path'])) {
      // Alter the theme path and template elements.
      $theme_registry[$key]['theme path'] = $module_path;
      $theme_registry[$key] = array_merge($theme_registry[$key], $template_file_object);
      $theme_registry[$key]['type'] = 'module';
    }
  }
}
```